# IOMMU not initializing properly for GPU Passthrough

Tags: cpu, virtualization, gpu, linux-kvm, qemu

Firstly here is my hardware:

- MB: GIGABYTE GA-X58A-UD9
- CPU: Intel Core i7 CPU X 980 @ 12x 3.326GHz
- GFX: AMD HD 6950, nVidia GTX 570(will be passthrough device)

I have followed the direction of various guides and was able to blog the nVidia device using pci_stub. In the GRUB config, I enable "iommu=on" and after restarting and making sure Virtualization was enabled in BIOS.

Upon restart I entered the command:

```
dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU
```

For which I got the reply

```
[     0.000000] Intel-IOMMUL enabled
```

and nothing else. I thought it was working but when I check for iommu_groups using

```
find /sys/kernel/iommu_groups/ -type l
```

It returned absolutely nothing. Can anyone help me troubleshoot as I have no idea what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an Intel processor I believe what you want your boot commandline to contain

```
intel_iommu=on
```

If you do this successfully you should see it in /proc/cmdline. For more details on seeing this up see [Alex Williamson's blog](http://vfio.blogspot.com/2015/05/vfio-gpu-how-to-series-part-3-host.html).